# TideSDK Constants

Tags: tidesdk

I have a couple of values that I'd like to set and have the app read for display. Originally, I tried setting a `key: value` pair in the `manifest` file, but found that that particular file is overwritten when the app is launched from the Developer app. The `tiapp.xml` file seems like the next logical choice. It looks like I can read custom properties from that, but I'd also like to read the `<version></version>` value and I don't see a way to do that. I'd hate to have to duplicate it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sigh**

Step away for a few hours. Come back. It's right in front of my face as `getVersion()`. I was so busy looking for the clever that I missed the obvious.